# Changing the scrollbar position with Workbook_BeforeSave() is not possible with all save buttons

Tags: vba, excel, business-objects

I'm working on an addition for our workbooks. The idea is that I want the workbooks to be saved with the scrollbars all the left and up regardless of where users scroll to while they edit them. I decided to do this with the code below, however I'm noticing different behavior with the save button in the workbook and the save button in the VBA code editor. When I save through the save button in the workbook, I see the scrollbars flicker after which they remain in the same spot. When I save through the save button in the code editor the scrollbars are scrolled all the way left and up as expected. I'm using the SAP BusinessObjects Analysis version: 2.4.2.67902 add-in with Excel.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)        
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. What you want to do is to make you scroll go to the top left every time you save ?

Comment: Can you confirm, that problem still occurs if you test this problem with the brand new xlsm file, wich contains _only_ those lines?

Comment: I'm asking this, because on my side it works as expected, regardless how I trying to save the workbook.

Comment: @CommonSense, thank you for your reply. I created a new, empty workbook and saved it to SAP NetWeaver Platform. I added the code above and again, I'm witnessing the same behavior. The save button in the code editor moves the cursors back whereas the save button in the workbook does not.

Comment: @CommonSense, I also tried to create a new macro-enabled workbook locally, applied the code, and both save buttons work as expected. Perhaps it's a problem with the SAP NetWeaver

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?